# Can I configure Prettier to automatically delete comments with specific patterns?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Let's say I have a bunch of comments that starts with `// DELETE ME`

Can I configure Prettier to automatically delete those comments?
If Prettier can't do that, is there another way to do such a task in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Remove Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-remove-comments) v1.4.0

It has the command: `remove-comments.removeAllCommentsWithPrefix` (**Comments: Remove All Comments that have a user entered prefix**)

When called it uses an Inputbox where you enter the prefix inclusive the whitespace.

You can also pass the prefix as an argument to the command.